# How to write the calculated formula for a column SPList to display total number of items in the list

Tags: sharepoint-server, calculated-column-formula

In the SharePoint List, total is being displayed. But I need to upate the total in a column of every item using calculated formula.
If this is possible can anyone help me with the calculated formula.

I have tried with =SUM(ID) , =Count(ID) , =MAX(ID)---But that is not the result I want.

Ex: There are 20 items in list. SoI need 20 printed in that entire column which I'm not able to fetch.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Calculated column does not support doing calculation for different items. If you need to get a column sum and list view total is not what you want, custom script will be your only option.

Here is a thread with similar question with some sample scripts you can have a try:
[Displaying sum value of a column in some other place in the page](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/148496/displaying-sum-value-of-a-column-in-some-other-place-in-the-page)

Comment: <%#Convert.ToInt32(((IList)((Repeater)Container.Parent).DataSource).Count)%>  
 Added this code in SharePoint ASP.Repeater to fetch count of all items. It is showing in the increasing order.

Can you please tell me if I am wrong at the code